# How do I change the Xenial.xml file?

Tags: 16.04, macbuntu

I want to change the Xenial.xml file to include MacBuntu wallpapers. For some reason, unknown to me, it won't let me include those wallpapers. I even considered even removing the default wallpapers, but I can't do that either. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple file that creates the .xml file used to rotate background images. Maybe it will work for you?

https://github.com/snowballrandom/UbuntuDesktopSlideshow

or you can check here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SlideshowWallpapers